# Matrix Manipulation/Transformation

Tags: matrices

I have three $n \times 1$ matrices:

$$ 
[A] =  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
a_1 \\ 
a_2 \\ 
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{array}  \right]
$$

$$ 
[B] =  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
b_1 \\ 
b_2 \\ 
\vdots\\
b_n
\end{array}  \right]
$$

$$ 
[C] =  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
a_1 b_1 \\ 
a_2 b_2 \\ 
\vdots\\
a_n b_n
\end{array}  \right]
$$

I want $[C]$ as a function of $[A]$ and $[B]$. To put it another way, if,

$$
[C]_{n \times 1} = [F]_{n \times n} [B]_{n \times 1}
$$

$$
[F]_{n \times n} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
a_1 &0&\dots&0&0 \\ 
0&a_2&0&\dots&0 \\ 
\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
0&\dots&0&a_{n-1}&0\\
0&0&\dots&0&a_n
\end{array}  \right]
$$
then, what is $[F]$ as a function of $[A]$?

**EDIT**

If what I am asking cannot be done, just tell me if there is a name for transformation $\Gamma$, below:

$$
\Gamma([A]) = [F]
$$

Or should I just define it myself in the manuscript.

Comment: Is it possible what you're asking cannot be done? How did you come across this question?

Comment: Do you mean to ask, what is another matrix $G$ such that $C = GA$?  If so, then I think you have your answer in front of you.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible. I'm writing a Finite difference library in C++ and I need that for the theoretical documentation.

Comment: @Mnifldz, No I do not mean that.

Comment: Sometimes the notation diag$(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is used to mean the matrix $F$ you want.